# Clone from gitblit returns 503

Tags: git, git-clone, gitblit

Whenever I try to clone a repository from gitblit 1.7.1 (running on Windows Server 2008), I get a 503 error.  However, this does not happen if I run the command on the server itself, even with the same URL:

Different machine:

```
$ git clone http://admin@server:9090/r/MyProject
Cloning into 'MyProject'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://admin@server:9090/r/MyProject/':  The requested URL returned error: 503
```

On the same server:

```
$ git clone http://admin@server:9090/r/MyProject
Cloning into 'MyProject'...
remote: Counting objects: 3725, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (3725/3725)
...
```

The last time I had a similar issue was scm-server when it had problems spawning a 'bash' process, but I cannot determine if this is the same problem.

I can't see any errors in the gitblit log files even though I set the logging to DEBUG (in the gitplit and log4j properties files).  Where else can I check what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to the global git proxy setting on the client machine.